# "You can do anything you set your mind to, man"

Tags: meaning-in-context, prepositions, idioms

In the song Lose Yourself by Eminem (which is by the way one of my favourite songs of all time), at the end he says:

> You can do anything you set your mind to, man.

Why do we need the "to" after "mind"? Note that I have understood the meaning of the sentence, but not the whole construction.

Comment: The phrase is typically "...set your mind to". Is the "in" really part of the lyric? Answer: Imagine it ends with the word "do" which is elided in the construction.

Comment: @shawnt00 You're right. There's no *in.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> "You can do anything you set your mind to,"

is a well known idiom in English (and has thus become something of a cliche). There is no good reason to deconstruct it, but you can see why the "to" is needed if you say it this way,

> "People can do anything **to which** they set their minds,"

but that still leaves the question, "What does **'set their minds'** mean?" So another way of saying this would be,

> "If you focus your mind on something, then you can achieve it."

I hope this helps.